# Pandas - convert a dataframe with over 10 columns to a dictionary with 3 values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe which consists of 10 columns. I want to convert the dataframe into a dictionary, but only need 3 of the columns within the dictionary.
My column list might look like: 'ID', 'AA','BB', 'CC', 'DD','EE','FF', 'GG', 'HH', 'II'.

I'd need my dictionary to look like something similar to the following (where I'm only pushing out the data for columns 'ID', 'AA', 'BB', and 'II'):
{'ID': 8747834, 'AA': 9348, 'BB':8010, 'II', 910}

What would be the best approach to do this?

Comment: Use `df.loc[:,['ID', 'AA', 'BB','II']].to_dict('records')`

Comment: `df[['ID','AA','BB','II']].to_dict()`?